# Mat-Select not displaying options

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm working inside an Angular app, and I'm trying to display some options, but for whatever reason, when the page is displayed, the options are missing, and there's no indication that an error was thrown (nothing in the console). I even tried doing a simpler version of it (without attaching it to the page model), but still nothing.

```
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Active</mat-label>
        <mat-select >
            <mat-option value="true" >True</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="false">False</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Does anyone see if there's a problem with the way I put this in? 
Side note: I have another mat-form-field right above that one that includes an input, but there's no problems with that one. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Strange. Are you displaying this conditionally?

Comment: Try clearing the browser cache.

Comment: Tried clearing the cache, and nothing. Also, there is a conditional in the div that's containing this, but it's a simple hidden attribute, and, since the container does appear, it doesn't look like that's the issue.

Comment: are you sure you are importing the MatSelectModule?

Comment: Yes, I am importing both the MatSelectModule and the MatOptionModule in the module. I don't know if this matters or not, but I am trying to use it in a BottomSheet view.

Comment: If there is no error only reason is either your container doesn't show or any css issues

Comment: You don't have to import the option module. Did you add the styles needed for theming?

Comment: Best would be if you could try and reproduce the issue in a StackBlitz :)

Answer (score 0):

For me, to make it work, BrowserAnimationsModule had to be imported in the app.module.ts file, and also a prebuilt theme for material had to be added.
I used:

`@import "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";`

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have imported browser animation module in your app.module.ts. it worked for me when i imported it.

Answer (score -1):

make sure to import the theme in style.css

```css
@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```